# Prove the following inequality using AM≥GM≥HM

Tags: inequality

$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c } + \frac{c}{a} ≥ \frac{a+b+c}{(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

where a , b, c are positive real numbers.

Comment: Please add the own thoughts, else there will be soon more downvotes before closing the question for the obvious reason of the omission of any bare context. Please insert the constraint from the title also in the OP, the title is rather a title, not a part of the question.

Comment: From the AM-GM inequality you have that $\frac{a/b+a/b+b/c}{3}\geq\frac{a}{(abc)^{1/3}}$, $\frac{b/c+b/c+c/a}{3}\geq\frac{b}{(abc)^{1/3}}$ and $\frac{c/a+c/a+a/b}{3}\geq\frac{c}{(abc)^{1/3}}$. Adding these three inequalities you get yours.